# Display Employees Names Who Have 2L's, SQL Query

Tags: sql

My code so far is:

```
select ename from emp where ename =ll%;
```

The question is, display all the names of all employees who have 2Ls in their name and are in department 30 or their manager is 7782;

I tried my code but it is giving me errors, I'm practicing for my test.

Comment: learn how to google if you're not going to listen in class.

Comment: @Justin, a bit harsh friend. That's no way to greet a new user. Even if their question pertains to *homework*. Clearly they did try something. Help them out or move to the next question. Side comments are unnecessary.

Comment: @Jason, understand your pov but I think only thing rohit tried was posting question here. I'm all for helping others but simply knowing what wildcards are is probably what his test is on in which case giving him the answer won't help him in the long run.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - This OP has asked 4 questions which all demonstrate in my opinion that they need to read a book. Posting random bits of syntax and asking why they don't work doesn't seem a particularly productive use of anyone's time IMO.

Comment: @Justin mate if you want to help just do it alright dnt need your side comments thanks others for helping.

Comment: @ Justin i do listen in class but my lecturer is useless so i find help from here, and i tried google but i thought i would get the best response here LOSER

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the like command and sandwich your ll's w/ % wild cards:

```
select ename from emp where ename like '%ll%'
```

Comment: +1 for beat me to the same answer. Here's [a link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "two l's like hello", or "two l's like lala"? If the second, this might work:

```
SELECT 
  ename FROM emp 
WHERE 
  ename LIKE '%l%l%' 
AND  
  (department = 30 AND manager = 7782)
```

If the first, change the `LIKE` to `%ll%` instead.

If `department` and `manager` are `CHAR/VARCHAR` instead of numeric, you'll need single quotes around them as well.

Comment: +1 for being thorough in regards to sequential `l`'s. Although there is no need to change `%l%l` to `%ll%` as `%` is wildcard (matches anything or nothing). Other than code purity of course. :)

Comment: But the first will match other than two sequential `l` chars (as in `lala` (can't come up with a word that works <g> - maybe someone whose vocabulary is more searchable can chime in here)), where the second will require two in exactly `ll` sequence.

Comment: I know. My only point is that the two examples are not mutually exclusive in the case of what `%l%l` matches. Meaning it matches both *hello* and *lala*. Whereas `%ll%` only matches *hello*. We're saying the same thing, I'm just coming at it from the other side :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from emp
Where instr(ename, 'l', 2, 2)>1 and
(Department=30 or manager=7782);
```

Here in instr function I start search from 2nd position to make it efficient. N no. Of occurance will be 2 as his query all about the 2nd 'l'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ename 
  FROM emp 
 WHERE (ename LIKE '%l%l%' 
    OR ename LIKE '%ll%')
   AND (department = 30 AND manager = 7782) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT ename  FROM emp
>   WHERE instr(ename,'L',1,2)>1 AND department =30 AND manager = 7782

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE LENGTH(ENAME)-LENGTH(REPLACE(ENAME,'L'))>=2;
```

It will work.